# I Can Only Live Where There is Light

Tags: riddle

I can only live where there is light, but I die if the light shines on me.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> A shadow

Only light creates

> shadows

of objects, but when light shines on it, it doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Another answer:

> **Photography film**. No one would say that a film unused is a living one, that is, it needs light to come alive for it's purpose. However, if the light shines on it, it ruins the exposure and becomes a 'dead film'.

Comment: that's a good one.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible answer (more literal):

> There are many plants which are adapted to shady environments (e.g. plants which typically grow on forest floors).  So, they obviously require indirect light to live, but if the sun shines directly on them too much, they shrivel up and die.